# Add a user profile field inside a document in another collection

Tags: firebase

I have two collections, one for registering properties and one registered users.

The collection for registering properties is called listings:

[image]

And the collection for registered users is called users
[image]

I can inject into the documents that are in the "listings" collection the id of the user who is logged in at that moment.

[image]

```js
let auth = getAuth()
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            // set user on formData
            formData = {
                ...formData,
                user: user.uid
            }
        } else {
            // goto('/profile');
        }
    })
```

What I want is to insert a field that is inside a document in the users collection into a document in the listings collection when I register a new property.

In this case the document inside the listings collection would get a new field: slug

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function to get the data I wanted

```js
// get reference to users collection
    const usersRef = collection(db, 'users')
    // get collection data
    getDocs(usersRef).then((snapshot) => {
        let userData = []
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            // get user data of current user
            if (doc.id === getAuth().currentUser.uid) {
                userData = doc.data()
            }
        })
        console.log(userData)
    })
```